# Create dropdown menu in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, dropdown

I want create dropdown menu like the following in react native and typescript.
Please suggest a way to do it on ios and android.
[dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzgUE.png)

Comment: picker (react-native), or react-native-material-dropdown

Answer (score 1):

There is a Picker component available from react-native library ([Link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker)).
You can also make use of libraries like native base ([Link](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-seperator-headref)). You then attach an onPress action action to it or you use react-native-popupmenu library but i'm having issues using it with type script.

Comment: Thanks my friend, It was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Check complete example to create dropdown menu ...

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, YellowBox} from "react-native";
import { Menu, MenuProvider, MenuOptions, MenuOption, MenuTrigger} from "react-native-popup-menu";

export default class HomeActivity extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
      'Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader'
    ]);
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <MenuProvider style={{ flexDirection: "column", padding: 30 }}>
        <Menu onSelect={value => alert(`You Clicked : ${value}`)}>

          <MenuTrigger  >
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>DropDown Menu</Text>
          </MenuTrigger  >

          <MenuOptions>
            <MenuOption value={"Login"}>
              <Text style={styles.menuContent}>Login</Text>
            </MenuOption>
            <MenuOption value={"Register"}>
              <Text style={styles.menuContent}>Register</Text>
            </MenuOption>
            <MenuOption value={"Download"}>
              <Text style={styles.menuContent}>Download</Text>
            </MenuOption>
            <MenuOption value={"Logout"}>
              <Text style={styles.menuContent}>Logout</Text>
            </MenuOption>
            <MenuOption value={3} disabled={true}>
              <Text style={styles.menuContent}>Disabled Menu</Text>
            </MenuOption>
          </MenuOptions>

        </Menu>
      </MenuProvider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    margin: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  menuContent: {
    color: "#000",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    padding: 2,
    fontSize: 20
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi just wondering, is there anyway to dynamically fill the MenuOptions?

Comment: Yeah, it is possible using react state object.